# Проблема чтения и записи в файл результата?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Зделал простую программу чтоб из файла убрал ненужные символы , некоторые символы заменил.Все, но почему-то пишет ошибка.Как решить?Пишу в pyChar--python 3.6(3.8)

```
f = open('topch.txt', 'r')
line = f.readlines()
while line:
    for i in line:
        lines = line[1].split(',')
        lines = lines.replace('"', "'")
        linew = lines[0].split(',')
        linew = open('\\newfile.txt', 'x')
        for text_line in line :
            Write_data.write(text_line)
            Write_data.close()
**Нашол в чем проблема в коде исправил но вышло так что не записывает в столбик только в строчку или каждый символ в столбик.(решено)
Строку такую взял на генераторе биткоинта для тренировки.
П.С.С Дополню при записи по чему то пишет еще такую ошибку...
Traceback (most recent call last):
Write_data.write(text_line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
Нечитабельный текст выходит.
https://prnt.sc/10kn65h**
```

Даже в файл не запись в файл:(
Как зделать читабельный текст?

Comment: `line[1].split(',')` --> `i.split(',')[1]`

Comment: i = line.split(',')[1]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: А почему до кода пишет девочка, а после кода - мальчик?

Comment: @МаркизАмри замените `line` на `i`

Comment: Эникейщик,  в каком смысле? Программа она же или ну может не правельно скланял.

Comment: Danis Заменил же код работает только с записью он по букве в столбик делает а в строчку каша ищу как разделить или чтоб столбик был .Если что-то не так напишите я немного не допонял.

Comment: Зачем вам такая толпа переменных, которые вы ещё и перезаписываете - то у вас в одной и той же переменной список, то файл, вы вообще понимаете, что у вас в коде происходит?

Comment: CrazyElf 17, я только учусь ,если есть лутше вариант так покажите я вот вообще не видел таких програм то что было написано в документации и то что изучил то и написал.Еще хотел прочитать строку из файла и воспользоватца вот этой библиотекой но увы почему то пишет ошибка.f = open('\\newfile2.txt', 'r')
    line = f.readlines()
    blockcypher.get_total_balance(line), та еще негде не написано как пользоватца библиотекой.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите, у вас когда вы вызвали `.split(',')`, вы получили список. А к списку нельзя применить метод `.replace`. `line[1].split(',')` =>  `line.split(',')[1]`.  Так мы берём второй элемент в списке, и это уже строка.

Comment: эх,уже делал посоветовали поменять менял все равно ошибка .Сейчас добавлю может что-то в строчке не так.А тогда как мне замену зделать лишних символов?

Answer (score 1):

Строчка `Write_data.close()` находится в цикле, поэтому файл закрывается сразу после первой итерации. Нужно вынести её из цикла

```
for text_line in line :    
    Write_data.write(text_line)
Write_data.close()
```

Comment: Понял, еще такая проблема что в файле строке в кучу, а не в столбик текст не читабельный становитца искал тут , даже на киберфоруме и доу но так , нет примера как строки в столбик и встрочку.